# Flutter: Firebase Google Auth not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I've tried building an app with a google login. Actually everything is working except after I have selected my google account it isn't switching to the next side. Moreover it just "reloads" the sign-in page. So how can I solve this problem that I get to the new page after signing in

This is my main code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'ProfileScreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Signin APP',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff9C58D2),
      ),
      home: GoogleSignApp(),
    );
  }
}

class GoogleSignApp extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override
  _GoogleSignAppState createState() => _GoogleSignAppState();
}

class _GoogleSignAppState extends State<GoogleSignApp> {

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {

   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
          content: new Text('Sign in'),
        ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

  FirebaseUser userDetails = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
        userDetails.providerId,
        userDetails.displayName,
        userDetails.photoUrl,
        userDetails.email,
        providerData,
);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new ProfileScreen(detailsUser: details),
      ),
    );
    return userDetails;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Image.network(
                   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518050947974-4be8c7469f0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
                   ,fit: BoxFit.fill,
                   color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate
                ),
              ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height:10.0),
             Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: Color(0xffffffff),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google,color: Color(0xffCE107C),),
                      SizedBox(width:10.0),
                      Text(
                      'Sign in with Google',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    ],),
                    onPressed: () => _signIn(context)
                              .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                              .catchError((e) => print(e)),
                  ),
                )
                ),

                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: Color(0xffffffff),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF,color: Color(0xff4754de),),
                      SizedBox(width:10.0),
                      Text(
                      'Sign in with Facebook',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    ],),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                )
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: Color(0xffffffff),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidEnvelope,color: Color(0xff4caf50),),
                      SizedBox(width:10.0),
                      Text(
                      'Sign in with Email',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    ],),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                )
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}



class UserDetails {
  final String providerDetails;
  final String userName;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String userEmail;
  final List<ProviderDetails> providerData;

  UserDetails(this.providerDetails,this.userName, this.photoUrl,this.userEmail, this.providerData);
}


class ProviderDetails {
  ProviderDetails(this.providerDetails);
  final String providerDetails;
}
```

And this is my second page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';



class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  ProfileScreen({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final GoogleSignIn _gSignIn =  GoogleSignIn();

    return  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text(detailsUser.userName),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: (){
               _gSignIn.signOut();
              print('Signed out');
               Navigator.pop(context);

            },
          ),
        ],
        ),
        body:Center(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage:NetworkImage(detailsUser.photoUrl),
                radius: 50.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(height:10.0),
               Text(
                "Name : " + detailsUser.userName,
                style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(height:10.0),
               Text(
                "Email : " + detailsUser.userEmail,
                style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(height:10.0),
              Text(
                "Provider : " + detailsUser.providerDetails,
                style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),)
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Google authentication to your app can be frustrating for a start.
I would suggest you take a look at the console while performing signing and look for any logs and share here with us.

You have used `catchError((e) => print(e)),` go through the logs.
Common errors while implementing google sign in:

1. API exception: 12500, => related to updating your information and filling the OAuth Consent Screen which is available on developers.google.com.
2. API exception 10 => related to dev error, maybe due to the unavailability of the SHA1 key in your application on Firebase.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I run my App and try to sign in this is all what shoes up:   
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(14665): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@544d628
D/FirebaseAuth(14665): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 5J64j7wOaEcsWPgKjBp56xQfJVX2 ).
I/flutter (14665): type 'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast

Comment: That is correct!! 
you are doing
```
FirebaseUser userDetails = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

`signInWithCredential` method returns `AuthResult`
to get a Firebase User you have to do it like this:

store the  final AuthResult _authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

Then,

`FirebaseUser _user = _authResult.user;`